# What's in a Docker Ubuntu Image

Tags: docker

I just downloaded a Ubuntu docker image, and now I'm confused. If Docker shares a common kernel among the containers, what's exactly inside an Ubuntu image? Which kernel is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all ask yourself what is Ubuntu ?

Ubuntu like CentOS, Arch and may others are Linux based distribution (distro). A distro is a operating system/software collection/packaging/philosophy based upon the Linux Kernel.

An Ubuntu docker image is the Software collection etc running in a container. It uses the host's Linux kernel.